# How does Facebook store it's log data?

Tags: facebook, logging, storage

I recently started using Scribe, Facebooks solution for transferring and collecting log data from many different servers.

What I could not find is how Facebook stores the huge amounts of log data it gets (according to a presentation it was 25TB per day in 2009).

Has Facebook released any information on how they do it? Hadoop HDFS? Cassandra?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They use Hive on top of Hadoop. Cassandra is used for their email/messaging, not logging. Some links:

https://developers.facebook.com/opensource/

http://highscalability.com/blog/2008/11/24/product-scribe-facebooks-scalable-logging-system.html

http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hive